# Can I determine 2-port s-parameters from 1-port measurements?

Tags: s-parameters

I have a 1-port impedance bridge. Can I get the four s-parameters of a 2-port device by measuring each "sending" port with the "receiving" port terminated in Z0 and reversing the measurement to get the remaining parameters in the other direction?

Comment: No the transmission loss can be independent of the port return loss. Consider if the return loss is infinite (perfect match) yet disconnected between ports.

Comment: To put specifics on Tony's post, consider two matched loads, versus an ideal length of transmission line. Zero reflection in both cases. Now if as well as a matched load, you also used a short or open to terminate the second port, you would have enough equations for your unknowns.

Comment: These both look like good "answer" candidates. Please, give me the opportunity to credit you both with my votes.